# HDD read head signal

Tags: sensor, signal, electromagnetic

I read that hard disk read heads use "giant magnetoresistance" so I assumed that I could measure a resistance change in the presence of a magnet.  Unfortunately I failed.

The read head came from a 3 headed Fujitsu laptop HDD.  It had 4 connections so I assumed two were read and two were write.  Once wired I measured about 5 ohms and 1/2 micro henry on both pairs and got no change placing or wiggling a magnet in front of it.  Connections were very difficult to make (microscope and air heater), but I am reasonably sure they were good. There was no connection between pairs.

Should I be able to measure a resistance change this way?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.

First of all, GMR heads need to be biased to a particular operating point in order to see the GMR effect at all.

Secondly, the heads are physically designed to be most sensitive to a magnetic field imposed across a tiny gap that rides very close to the surface of the disk. On a modern HDD, that gap is *extremely* narrow — it's actually smaller than the tiniest transistors in a modern VLSI chip! To whatever extent is possible, the head is designed to be *insensitive* to all other imposed magnetic fields.

Comment: How can I figure out the bias point etc?  My thought was to use the head to create a scanning magnetic image of a smooth surface...  The tiny gap and insensitivity to external field is a great advantage for that purpose.  Visually, the head has no features other than the geometry to make it fly on the air gap.

Comment: This sensors are made to detect magnetic dipoles of the size of a few nanometers in a distance of a few nanometers. If your field are in the 100nm range, they will already be too large and look like external fields for the sensor. Sure you can use it? I'd use a tiny hall sensor, the resolution can be 1mm.